# Copy build to a different directory after finishing building

Tags: xcode

When I build my project with Xcode 8, it saves the final build in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-[add-lots-of-random-chars-here]/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos`. Is there any way to make Xcode copy the app bundle to a user-specified path after building it? e.g. how can I make Xcode copy the built app bundle to `/MyBuilds` after building it?

I know that I can change the path for storing derived data in my project's settings in Xcode but doing so will of course make Xcode store all data (including intermediate stuff like object code etc) in this location which I don't want. I really only want Xcode to copy the final, ready-for-distribution app bundle to a user-specified location without any intermediate files used in the build process.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution using a script in "Build Phases" does not work properly since Xcode is not finished building the app when running the script. Here is a solution with a script that runs after all build tasks are finished:

1. Go to "Edit Scheme"
2. Click on the triangle next to "Build"
3. Select "Post-action"
4. Press the + button and select "New Run Script Option"
5. Select your app name in "Provide build settings from"
6. Add the following shell script:

Script:

```
PRODUCT="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app"
cp -R "${PRODUCT}" ~/Desktop
```

[image: Edit Schemes]

Comment: this isn't doing anything for me.  Is there any way to check to see if the script is even running?

Comment: If you want to copy it to project dir you can instead use something like this:
```PRODUCT="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework"
DESTINATION="${SRCROOT}/build"
mkdir -p "${DESTINATION}"
cp -R "${PRODUCT}" "${DESTINATION}"```

Answer (score 3):

Add a shell script to your build phases to copy the product:

[image]

Script:

```
PRODUCT="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app"
cp -R "${PRODUCT}" ~/Desktop
```

Certainly replace `~/Desktop` with a target directory of your choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly when archiving products because Xcode still does important build steps *after* running the script, e.g. stripping and codesigning are done *after* running the script so the app bundle copied to the new location isn't stripped and codesigned correctly. Any other ideas?

Comment: When archiving you can choose a path where to export the ipa. What is your actual issue while archiving?

Comment: This is the solution for me, for some weird reason.